# How to get only the first ten bytes of a binary file

Tags: bash, binary

I am writing a bash script that needs to get the header (first 10 bytes) of a file and then in another section get everything except the first 10 bytes.  These are binary files and will likely have `\0`'s and `\n`'s throughout the first 10 bytes.  It seems like most utilities work with ASCII files.  What is a good way to achieve this task?

Comment: For anyone in need of the hex output see this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10882/103618

Answer (score 200, accepted):

To get the first 10 bytes, as noted already:

```
head -c 10
```

To get all but the first 10 bytes (at least with GNU `tail`):

```
tail -c+11
```

Comment: Yes.  I liked the `dd` idea but this option does not require a change in buffer size so it works well with huge files.  Thanks.

Comment: Instead of opening same file two times, you could `(head;cat)<file`!  Have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71979980/1765658)

Answer (score 59):

`head -c 10` does the right thing here.

Comment: It is interesting that this answer was the first one, it is correct, but the others have much more upvotes.

Comment: @robert This may be because this is only a partial answer.

Answer (score 38):

You can use the [`dd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html) command to copy an arbitrary number of bytes from a binary file.

```
dd if=infile of=outfile1 bs=10 count=1
dd if=infile of=outfile2 bs=10 skip=1
```

Comment: This works but it's quite slow.  The bs of 10 is killing these huge files.  Is there a quicker way to skip the first ten bytes?  It seems so simple.

Comment: `dd`  is not reliable. It may read fewer bytes than requested for many different reasons.

Comment: @ceving could you mention at least one of those reasons?  I'm not sure I believe you.

Comment: The following example prints 1 instead of 2: `{ printf a; sleep 1; printf b; } | dd bs=2 count=1 2>/dev/null | wc -c`

Comment: The explanation is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/7167) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/563207/7167)

Comment: @ceving you have to use  `iflag=fullblock` in your `{ printf a; sleep 1; printf b; }|cat | dd bs=2 count=1 iflag=fullblock 2>/dev/null | wc -c`. See `man dd` and `dd --help`

Comment: @F.Hauri In general it is a good idea to do so, because it is necessary for pipes. But I think for files it is sufficient without.

Comment: [**Do not use:** `dd bs=10 skip=1 of=body.part` on big file!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71979980/1765658)

Answer (score 3):

**Edit Oct 8 2023**: Add limitations chapter and How to split at line number with little explanation about unbuffered I/O.

## How to split a *stream* (or a *file*) under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Reading SO request:

> get the header (first 10 bytes) of a file and then in another section get everything except the first 10 bytes.

I understand:

> ***How to split a file at specific point***

As all answers here does access ***same file two time***, instead of just ***split*** them...

#### Here is my two cents:

The interesting thing using Un*x is considering every **whole** job as a ***filter***, it's easy to a split *stream* using ***unbuffered I/O***. Most of standard un*x tools (`cat`, `grep`, `awk`, `sed`, `python`, `perl` ...) work as filters.

### 1. Using `head` or `dd` but in a single pass

```bash
{ head -c 10 >head_part; cat >tail_part;} <file
```

This is the more efficient, as your file is read only 1 time, the first 10 byte goes to `head_part` and the rest goes to `tail_part`.

Note: second redirection `>tail_part` could be place outside of whole *list* (`{ ...;}`) as well...

#### You could do same, using `dd`:

{ dd count=1 bs=10 of=head_part; cat;} tail_part

This stay more efficient than running two process of `dd` to open same file two times.

...And still use standard *block size* for the rest of file:

**Do not use:**

```bash
dd bs=10 skip=1 of=body.part
```

(as suggested on other posts) on big file!!! This tell `dd` to process the **whole** file by block of only 10 bytes! This will work, but will  be slow and consume a lot of processor resources!!

#### Another sample based on *read by line*:

Split HTTP (or mail) stream on *near empty* line  (line containing only *carriage return*: `\r`):

```bash
nc google.com 80 <<<$'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r' |
    { sed -u '/^\r$/q' >/tmp/so_head.raw; cat;} >/tmp/so_body.raw
```

or, to drop empty header delimitation line:

```bash
nc google.com 80 <<<$'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r' |
    { sed -nu '/^\r$/q;p' >/tmp/so_head.raw; cat;} >/tmp/so_body.raw
```

This will produce two files:

```bash
ls -l so_*.raw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root           307 Apr 25 11:40  so_head.raw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root           219 Apr 25 11:40  so_body.raw

grep www so_*.raw
so_body.raw:<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
so_head.raw:Location: http://www.google.com/
```

### 2. Pure bash way:

If the goal is to obtain *values of first 10 bytes*  in a usable [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variable, here is a nice and efficient way:

Because ten byte are few, fork to `head` could be avoided. from [Read a file by bytes in BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13890319/1765658):

```bash
read8() {
    local _r8_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r8_car LANG=C IFS=
    read -r -d '' -n 1 _r8_car || { printf -v $_r8_var '';return 1;}
    printf -v $_r8_var %02X "'"$_r8_car
}
{ 
    first10=()
    for i in {0..9};do
        read8 first10[i] || break
    done
    cat
 } < "$infile" >"$outfile"
```

This will create an array `${first10[@]}` containing hexadecimal values of first ten bytes of `$infile` and store rest of data into `$outfile`.

```bash
declare -p first10

declare -a first10=([0]="25" [1]="50" [2]="44" [3]="46" [4]="2D" [5]="31" [6]="2E"
[7]="34" [8]="0A" [9]="25")
```

This was a PDF (`%PDF` -> `25 50 44 46`)... Here's another sample:

```bash
{
    first10=()
    for i in {0..9};do
        read8 first10[i] || break
    done
    cat
} <<<"Hello world!"
d!
```

As I didn't redirect output, string `d!` will be output on terminal.

```bash
echo ${first10[@]}
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C

printf '%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b%b\n' ${first10[@]/#/\\x}
Hello worl
```

### 3. Limitations

If this work fine by using `dd` or `head -c` this could become problematic using `head -n`, for sample:

```bash
seq 1 4 | ( dd bs=3 count=1 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^/1:/'; sed s/^/2:/  )
1:1
1:22:
2:3
2:4
```

where `seq` output are splitted at third byte (just before *newline*)

```bash
seq 1 4 | ( head -c 3 | sed 's/^/1:/'; sed s/^/2:/  )
1:1
1:22:
2:3
2:4
```

But if you try to split file at second line:

```bash
seq 1 4 | ( head -n 2 | sed 's/^/1:/'; sed s/^/2:/  )
1:1
1:2
```

The last part of *STDIN* disappear... This is due to the working of `head`. Reading whole buffer in order to find *end of line* separator,
once buffer size are read, this don't exist anymore in *STDIN*.

#### 3.1 How to split a stream (or a file) at specific *line number*

For splitting at line number, you should use `sed`, with `-u` (*`unbuffered`*)  option: 
 instead of `head -n $lineNumber`, use: `sed -ue ${lineNumber}q`

```bash
seq 1 4 | ( sed -u 2q | sed 's/^/1:/'; sed s/^/2:/  )
1:1
1:2
2:3
2:4
```

As `sed` read *STDIN* by line, *unbuffered*, when `q` (*`quit`*)  are executed, *STDIN* still hold ***the whole rest of input***.

### 4. About binary

You said:

> These are binary files and will likely have `\0`'s and `\n`'s throughout the first 10 bytes.

```bash
{
    first10=()
    for i in {0..9};do
        read8 first10[i] || break
    done
    cat
} < <(gzip <<<"Hello world!") >/dev/null 

echo ${first10[@]}
1F 8B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 03
```

( Sample with a `\n` at bottom of this ;)

### 5. As a function

```bash
read8() { local _r8_var=${1:-OUTBIN} _r8_car LANG=C IFS=
    read -r -d '' -n 1 _r8_car || { printf -v $_r8_var '';return 1;}
    printf -v $_r8_var %02X "'"$_r8_car ;}
get10() {
    local -n result=${1:-first10}     # 1st arg is array name
    local -i _i
    result=()
    for ((_i=0;_i<${2:-10};_i++));do  # 2nd arg is number of bytes
        read8 result[_i] || { unset result[_i] ; return 1 ;}
    done
    cat
}
```

Then (here, I use the special character `⛶` as *symbol* for: *there was **no** newline*. ).

```bash
get10 pdf 4 <$infile >$outfile
printf %b ${pdf[@]/#/\\x}
%PDF⛶

echo $(( $(stat -c %s $infile) - $(stat -c %s $outfile) ))
4

get10 test 8 <<<'Hello world'
rld

printf %b ${test[@]/#/\\x}
Hello Wo⛶

get10 test 24 <<<'Hello World!'
printf %b ${test[@]/#/\\x}
Hello World!
```

( And the last character printed is a `\n`! ;)

#### Final binary demo:

```bash
get10 test 256 < <(gzip <<<'Hello world!')

printf '%b' ${test[@]/#/\\x} | gunzip 
Hello world!

printf "  %s %s %s %s  %s %s %s %s    %s %s %s %s  %s %s %s %s\n" ${test[@]}
  1F 8B 08 00  00 00 00 00    00 03 F3 48  CD C9 C9 57
  28 CF 2F CA  49 51 E4 02    00 41 E4 A9  B2 0D 00 00
  00
```

**Note!!** This work fine and is very quick while number of byte to read stay low, even processing large files. This could be used for file recognition, for sample. But for spliting files on larger parts, you have to use `split`, `head`, `tail` and/or `dd`.