# unix grep n-bytes at specific position in file

Tags: unix, grep, cut

I have a file containing text and I want to get 100 characters starting at a position 5010. 
I tried grep and cut but couldnt figure it out without having a pattern for grep and knowing the line for cut.
It is probably very easy, so any quick help is appreciated!

EDIT (commands I tried):

```
cut -c5010-5110 file.txt

grep -zoP '.{5010}\K.' file.txt

grep '^.{5010}' file.txt
```

Comment: bytes or characters?

Comment: please share a [mcve] so we can know exactly what you are doing here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411014/how-to-get-only-the-first-ten-bytes-of-a-binary-file might help... for ex: `head -c 7 ip.txt | tail -c+3` to get 5 characters starting from 3rd position

Comment: Would you like a perl  script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dd](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/dd-invocation.html):

```
dd if=file.txt of=output.txt bs=1 count=100 skip=5010
```

But I'm still not sure if this works with multi-byte characters. Its just bytes...