# Is there a way within a bash script to determine the minimum java version required by a jar file containing class files and jar files?

Tags: java, bash, javap

For a single class - we can work out the version of Java used to compile it:

```
javap -verbose className
```

I have a scenario where I need to scale this up to a jar file containing many classes and jar files.

My question is: **Is there a way within a bash script to determine the java version required by a jar file containing class files and jar files?**

Comment: A "jar file containing ... jar files"?

Comment: You can scan the class file or jar with [THIS](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/105-determine-java-class-file-version) to avoid having to extract anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the JAR file and check the ***MANIFEST.MF*** file, which contains information about the JDK used to build the JAR. The "Created-By" or "Build-Jdk" header in the ***MANIFEST.MF*** file stores the JDK version used to create the JAR

replace JarName.jar with your jar

here is the bash script to find the jdk version:

```
#!/bin/bash
jdk_version=$(unzip -p JarName.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | grep "Created-By\|Build-Jdk")
echo $jdk_version
```

Comment: Note that the headers are not mandatory so it is not guaranteed that the JAR's MANIFEST file will contain _Created-By_ or _Build-Jdk_. Refer to the [JAR] [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/jar/jar.html).

Answer (score 2):

A JAR file is just a collection of files. It's not guaranteed that every `.class` file in the JAR was compiled with the same JDK version - although I believe that the chances of encountering such a JAR file are very slim. Nonetheless, the Java class [major] version number is **always** the seventh and eighth bytes in a `.class` file.

Assuming that all `.class` files in the JAR have the same version, you can use the [jar](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jar.html) command to extract a `.class` file from the JAR and read the bytes that contain the Java version.

Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file for details of the Java `.class` file format.

Refer to [SO question] [How to get only the first ten bytes of a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411014/how-to-get-only-the-first-ten-bytes-of-a-binary-file) for how to read the first bytes of the `.class` file.